# What keyboard shortcuts can I use that are not predefined or blocked by browsers?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, progressive-web-apps

I am building a web app and I want to add keyboard shortcuts to the page. The problem is, that I don't know which keyboard shortcuts are already defined by the different browsers.

The web page can override some shortcuts, for example cmd+s, while it cannot override cmd+t for example.

I want to avoid overriding keyboard shortcuts that the browser already provides, even if it's possible, because some users may use them and expect them to work on my page. Overriding would then do something different that the user did not expect.

Another difficulty is the difference between browsers, where one shortcut may be used by chrome, while firefox uses a different one for the same thing.

**Where can I find a list with predefined keyboard shortcuts for the different browsers?**

Answer (score 0):

A list of shortcuts for each browser can be found here:

- [Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-edge-50d3edab-30d9-c7e4-21ce-37fe2713cfad)
- [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179)
- [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly)
- [Safari](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/keyboard-and-other-shortcuts-cpsh003/mac)

And for the less frequently used browsers:

- [Brave](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360032272171)
- [Opera](https://help.opera.com/en/latest/shortcuts/)
- [Internet Explorer (Unofficial doc)](https://shortcutworld.com/Internet-Explorer/win/Internet-Explorer_Shortcuts)